# Triggering a change() event to refresh select box causes live change event to retrigger

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

What I'm doing is simple so I'm probably doing it wrong.

I have a simple select box as a filter for a table. I have a button to reset the filter.

```
$("#package").live('change', function()
{   
    filterPackage = $("#package").val();

    $.ajax({url: 'ajaxAllGroups.php?filterPackage='+filterPackage, cache: false, success: function(main)
    {
        $('#fullPartsList').html(main);
    }});
});

function unfilter()
{
    $.ajax({url: 'ajaxAllGroups.php?filterPackage=0', cache: false, success: function(main)
    {
        $('#fullPartsList').html(main); // Send ajax content to table

        $('#package').val(0); // Reset option to default
        $("#package").change(); // Force visual change to select box
    }});
}
```

As you can see the reset button sets the select option back to zero and I trigger the change() function on the select to visual make the change apply to the select box.

It all works but that visual-only change triggers the live change function above which causes a second unnecessary ajax call.

I thought about doing this with a true/false variable to make it run once but couldn't get the variable to set true/false at the right time, however I am sure there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the  $('#package').val(0); trigger a change event ?

Comment: @benzonico it should, shouldn't it? and then the manual trigger is unnecessary

Comment: @benzonico - I wish it did in this case and I can't think of a case where I'd like it otherwise but it doesn't and I can see why from a flexibility perspective.

Comment: Changing a value programatically will not trigger the change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a simple check in the live action handler to exclude calls for value 0.

```
if(filterPackage!=0)
{
    $.ajax({url: 'ajaxAllGroups.php?filterPackage='+filterPackage, cache: false, success: function(main)
    {
        $('#fullPartsList').html(main);
    }});
}
```

Comment: Both of your answers are fantastic. This was simpler than I thought and I'm ashamed to have not thought of this. I'm tempted to give the answer to adeneo because it does simplify the whole thing and is probably more applicable to wide scenarios but you were first and might appreciate the rep more :) Thank you.

Comment: Although this is a good solution I found a slight flaw in that my option(0) was labelled "All" rather than "Select One", hence I couldn't unfilter by selecting "All" with the drop down, only with the "Unfilter" button. I love this as an easy method but for those in my position it may not be quite perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '#package', function() {
    doFilter(this.value);
});

function doFilter(pkg) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajaxAllGroups.php',
        data: {filterPackage: pkg}
    }).done(function(main) {
        $('#fullPartsList').html(main);
    });
}

function unfilter() {
    $('#package').val(0);
    doFilter(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you adeneo - please see comment on answer above. I think this is neater and I will adapt my function to this method and try and think a bit more like this in future coding. Wish I could give this an answer mark too :)

Comment: @JamesPitt - No problem! Just happy to help!